# setBarTintColor after view is loaded

Tags: ios

I have an application that grabs configuration values from a remote source on initial launch. One of those values is the `navigationBar` `tintColor`

In my `viewWillAppear` I have this:

```
UINavigationBar *navigationBar = self.navigationController.navigationBar;
[navigationBar setBarTintColor:[self UIColorFromRGB:config.navColor]];
[navigationBar setNeedsDisplay];
NSLog( @"Color after SND: %@", config.navColor );
```

When the app launches, this prints to the console:

```
Color after SND: 39589a
```

Consequently, the `barTintColor` is the expected blue.

When the sync completes, I manually call `viewWillAppear` (as well as `viewDidLoad`) and everything except `barTintColor` in the interface adjusts as expected. I also get what I would expect printing to the console:

```
Color after SND: a1231c
```

But the barTintColor remains the same until I close the application and launch it again (the sync isn't re-triggered when the app launches a second time).

Any ideas what I am missing to force the `navigationBar` `tintColor` to update after the view has already loaded?

**EDIT:**
To be clear that it isn't `UIColorFromRGB` that is interfering, I have performed two tests:

1. This: `NSLog( @"UIColor Result: %@", [UIColor redColor] );` and this: `NSLog( @"UIColor Result: %@", [self UIColorFromRGB:@"ff0000"] );` both produce this: `UIColor Result: UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 1 0 0 1`
2. I added this:

   if( updateBarColor )
   {
      NSLog( @"setting to red" );
      UINavigationBar *navigationBar = self.navigationController.navigationBar;
      [navigationBar setBarTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
      [navigationBar setNeedsDisplay];
   }

Which printed the expected message to the console, but did not alter the color of the navigation bar.

Comment: I REALLY don't think you should be calling `viewDidAppear` and `viewDidLoad` yourself.

Comment: what version of iOS? setBarTintColor and setTintColor do different things on different versions. Try calling setTintColor instead/also and see what it does!

Comment: @RobP iOS 7.0, 7.1 and 8.1. I played with those out of frustration, but, actually, they aren't the same thing. `barTintColor` is what is applied to the background of the bar and `tintColor` is what is applied to the navigation items and bar button items. https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationBar_Class/index.html

Comment: @LordZsolt Perhaps you're right, but the alternative is to put the same code in its own method and call that code both from this spot and from viewDidLoad/viewWillAppear. 6 of one... I do see people on the Internet saying that, "Apple says don't do it," but I can't find Apple actually saying that anywhere. If you can provide a link to Apple documentation saying that it's a bad idea (or a well-written & researched argument against it), I'll change the error of my ways.

Answer (score 0):

If your fire the change of the navigationBarTinColor, It change automatically.

You can test this, in any action:

```
     UINavigationBar *navBar = self.navigationController.navigationBar;
[navBar setBarTintColor: [UIColor blueColor]];
```

Test this before in order to know that the problem is your method: UIColorFromRGB (in other order of things method should start with lower case).

Another problem is you are two navigation Controller nested.

Comment: To prove that I had a valid `UIColor` returning from my own `UIColorFromRGB` I added this: `NSLog( @"UIColor after SND: %@", [self UIColorFromRGB:config.navColor] );` And the initial launch logged this: `UIColor after SND: UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0.223529 0.345098 0.603922 1` After sync logged this: `UIColor after SND: UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0.631373 0.137255 0.109804 1` but still no color change. I would agree that it "should" change automatically with `setBarTintColor` but it doesn't. That's why I posted.

Comment: I don't understand "you are two navigation Controller nested." Are you referring to the fact that my variable is `navigationBar`? If so, that's now a problem. `self.navigationController.navigationBar` has its own scope, plus (on a whim) I have tried changing the variable name to something else, and it had no affect.

Comment: Sorry you can text changing in your code this [self UIColorFromRGB:config.navColor] to this: [UIColor redColor] ?

Comment: More things, You don´t need [navigationBar setNeedsDisplay];. I made a simple App with a button with its action, and press the button only with the line: self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor redColor], change the color automatically. In order to find what´s wrong: You must do: 1.- Log the NavigationController and see it exist: NSLog(@"My Nav Controller %@",[self.navigationController description]); 2.- Hidden the navigationBar, after change the color in viewWillAppear.

Answer (score 0):

Well, what stumped me was that the methods were all firing in the right order, all other UI elements were being properly updated, everything was printing to the console as expected, and I had followed all the suggestions I could find online. The detail that I had missed is that the update process (getting configuration values from a remote source) was happening on a background thread, and that particular UI change, apparently, can't be triggered from a background thread. I created a new method in my top-level view controller:

```
-(void)updateBarColor
{
    SFConfig *freshConfig = [[SFConfig alloc] init];
    UINavigationBar *navBar = self.navigationController.navigationBar;
    [navBar setBarTintColor:[self UIColorFromRGB:freshConfig.navColor]];
}
```

Then invoked it after the needed data was received with:

```
[viewController performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateBarColor) withObject:viewController waitUntilDone:NO];
```